# How to use distinct, only in one column from a table using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have to show the distinct values only in one column with other other columns in the table.

Which means, the distinct rule has to apply in one column and all the other column has to be shown in single table.

I have tried this query:

```
select distinct column_name, * from Table_name.
select distinct table_name.* from table_name
```

It is not working.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: ---------------------
myTable:

id   posX    posY

1      35     565
3      89     224
6      11     456
14     89    475
---------------------
For Example, the myTable has some duplication values in the pos x column: 89.
I have to retreive those duplication values, along with other columns.
//id and POS Y.//


Friends says, Duplication will only apply for one columns.
So I have decided to take a count of "Distinct" query of the particular column and I run this query

select * from mytable
group by pos X.

Still they said, that I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know why my comment is appearing like that.

Comment: Can someone edit my first comment.

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: You can edit your question to insert the info from your first comment. That way you can apply the advanced formatting features which are simply not available in comments. Use this to do so [edit]. Please also add the desired output, i.e. how should the result look like, just type it. It might help to understand what the goal of this question actually is.